# Capitalize each first letter of each word in a String that is wrapped in asterisks from markdown. Allow for multiple words in asterisks

Tags: java, markdown

I have a Spring blog. In the Post model, I wrote a method that capitalizes each first letter of each word in a Post's title. This works fine. However, the input field when creating the title allows for bold and italic options via a markdown editor, which then wraps words in asterisks. This is where the issues arise.

A bold or italicized word gets capitalized as long as it's the only word wrapped in asterisks. But, if two or more words are conveniently wrapped all together, like a book or movie title that has spaces in between words, it breaks and says "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:"

In the if statements, I've tried using word.charAt(i) == ' ' to check if there's an empty space but I can't seem to figure it out as sometimes it will capitalize the second word after the space, like "word Word" but then 
the first word gets neglected.

I simply want to capitalize every word so that

```
italics: *word word*
bold: **word word**
both: ***word word***
```

returns *Word Word* , **Word Word**, or both respectively.

Is this even a good approach? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

```
 public String makeTitleUppercase(String title) {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    String[] sentence = title.split(" ");

    for (String word : sentence) {
        char[] letters = word.trim().toCharArray();

        //Capitalize each first letter of each word (works):
        letters[0] = Character.toUpperCase(letters[0]);

        //Capitalizing bold and italicized markdown (issues):
        for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {

            //word.charAt(i) == ' ' where???

            // *italics*:
            if (word.charAt(i) == '*') {
                letters[1] = Character.toUpperCase(letters[1]);

                //**bold**:
                if (word.charAt(i + 1) == '*') {
                    letters[2] = Character.toUpperCase(letters[2]);
                }

                //***both***  
                if (word.charAt(i + 2) == '*') {
                    letters[3] = Character.toUpperCase(letters[3]);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        word = new String(letters);
        sb.append(word).append(" ");
        System.out.println("get here");
    }
    return sb.toString().trim();
}
```

Comment: For starters, the code has some glaring errors.  If you're looking at the last character of the string (`for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)`) what's going to happen when you do `word.charAt(i + 1)` and also `+ 2` ?

Comment: _"Is accounting for these asterisks even necessary"_ -- I'm not sure what this question means.  If you don't "account for" them, how do you expect to interpret them and perform the desired highlighting?

Comment: @Jim Wait you understand how the code, the explanation and the examples play together? The whole specification is garbled.

Comment: @Voo No, the question is rather unclear.

Comment: @Jim, thanks for the reply. Sorry for being unclear. I have since removed that small bit. I was focusing too much on the asterisks themselves when it was better to skip them. John's answer below helped convey that much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've gotten yourself a bit into trouble by focusing on the details of the markdown formatting.  Note in particular that you scan each word for asterisks regardless of whether you've already successfully capitalized the first letter; this results in your exception when between one and three asterisks appear at the end of the word.

You should generalize your characterization a bit, so that the formatting is not handled as a special case.  For instance, the rule you want might be "in each whitespace-delimited word, skip any asterisks and capitalize the next character, if any".  After the tokenization, that might look like this:

```
        char[] letters = word.toCharArray(); // no need to trim()

        for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
            if (letters[i] != '*') {
                // Capitalize the first non-asterisk (even if that doesn't change it)
                letters[i] = Character.toUpperCase(letters[i]);
                // No need to look any further
                break;
            }
        }
        // That's it for capitalizing!
```

Special cases complicate your reasoning.  Sometimes they cannot be avoided, but when you have the choice to just be more general, it's usually a win.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, John. I feared as much that I was getting into trouble focusing too much on the details of that markdown. The rule you suggested was exactly what I was trying to convey, thanks for clearing that up for me. It worked perfectly. I really appreciate your time! I tried up-voting but I don't have enough rep for it to show but for those reading this would be the best answer.

Comment: @RyanH, if you are satisfied with this answer then you, as the author of the question, can "accept" it by clicking on the check mark near the voting buttons, independently of whether you can or do vote it up.